# ProgressDialog spinner doesn't appear while the dialog do (no spinner at all)

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

I am new to android development and stuff. Working on an existing android application and tried to use progressDialogue the spinner one.

I have declared the progressdialog kinda globally. showing and dismissing them in separate methods both of which run on ui thread.

```
 private void progressShow()
{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //progress_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this,R.style.Theme_IAPTheme);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Authenticating...");
            progressDialog.show();



            login_button.setEnabled(false);
            register_button.setEnabled(false);
            user_name_edit_text.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
}
```

The code above is working fine but the style of the progressdialog is very dumb. When I don't mention R.style.Theme_IAPTheme the style is a good one but there is no spinner there.

How would I get some other style?(I am learning from this link:http://sourcey.com/beautiful-android-login-and-signup-screens-with-material-design/). This guy used  R.style.AppTheme_Dark_Dialog which becomes red for me when I use it. :DDDD

Comment: you may not use a theme at all and define the dialog like this `progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this)` and the dialog will be themed with device default dialog theme!

Comment: Yeah @AtefHares ..exactly in that case the spinner doesn't appear...

Answer (score 0):

One of the great things about android is availability of so many open source libraries. If you're not satisfied by the style of progress dialog you can use a custom one. Refer to this [URL](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/76), a list of few fancy progress dialogs you might like.

Answer (score 0):

Are transitions turned off in developer options on the device.
This can cause certain animations from the system to not display. Unfortunately, that includes the progress dialog spinner.